# How to Specify XML Element for Java Record classes in java17

Tags: xml, java-17, java-21

I java 17 a Java Record class, how can i customize the XML Serialization attributes like  `@XmlElement`  `@XmlRootElement`

```
public record Person(String name, int age) {
    // Some record body
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify the class level annotations at Record level, and field level at Constructor arg level

```
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public record Person(@XmlElement String name, @XmlElement int age) {
    // body
}
```